# How to add many items to List of String at the same time

Tags: swift, realm

Do you know guys how to add many items to List of Strings in Realm?
I tried something like:

```
data.list.append = (["item1", "item2", "item3", "..."]) etc
```

but it doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

why not to try `array.append(contentsOf: ["item1", "item2", "..."])`

Comment: Append doesn’t have a parameter “contentsOf”, but Insert is what I looking for. I can insert a collection to List at any position I want. Thanks for tip

Comment: @iMat Yes it does. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2854129-append

Answer (score 0):

Although it might slow down your compilation process, you can also use the `+=` overloaded operator to concatenate two arrays.
For instance:

```
let a = [1,2,3]
var b = [4,5,6]
b+=a // b = [4,5,6,1,2,3]
```